# Going back to original alias after GAE migration

Tags: google-app-engine, migration, google-cloud-datastore

I have just completed a migration from a master/slave to HRD. During this migration I was forced to change my app name from myapp.appspot.com to myapp-hrd.appspot.com. I have set up an alias so my users can still use the old site url.

But I find it rather messy to have two apps where the one just forward requests to the other.

Is there any way I can migrate my new myapp-hrd back to myapp?

The only way I can think of is to erase my old myapp and then migrate from myapp-hrd to it, but it takes 3 days to delete an GAE app. And 3 days downtime is not an option. I have to keep myapp running since the url is hardcoded in a lot of android phones.

Answer (score 1):

Even if you delete your old app, you won't be able to create a new app with the same identifier. Did you use the migration tool? If so, the new application should now be serving both the new and old app URLs. Otherwise, I recommend you [report a production issue](http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/entry?template=Production%20issue) so that someone from Google links the apps manually.

Comment: Yes, the migration went OK. But I find it messy to have two apps where one is just there doing nothing. As I try to say in the question header I would like to only have _one_ app after the migration and due to android it must be the original one.

Comment: @TheisBorg let me clarify. I also used the tool and since, both myapp and myapp-hdr point to the new app (myapp-hdr), so you should be able to delete the old app and keep the old URL. Make sure it doesn't actually work like that and do contact someone if not, because it should.